# How do I make both the Standard Unity Sphere and Pro Builder Sphere behave the same way?

Tags: unity, physics

I recently got into Unity and have been developing a game with a co-worker. Long story short I was thinking about using Blender for the 3d models but found about ProBuilder and gave it a shot. Here's my problem/question...

Take this code for test:

```
 public Rigidbody rigiBody;

[Range(200,800)]
public float jumpForce;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Awake()
{
    rigiBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        rigiBody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Force);
    }
}
```

When I create a 3D object within Unity (r-click on hierarchy panel -> 3d object -> sphere, Scale[x:1,y:1,z:1]) and add a rigid body component and the script above the sphere jump feel just about right.

When using a ProBuilder object (New Shape Tool -> Cone [Radius: .5, Height: 2, Number of Sides: 32] -> Build Cone) and and add a rigid body component and the script above the cone just drop very fast and the jump force applied almost don't have any impact on it. Rigid Body's settings are default for both objects.

How do I make both the Standard Unity Shape (Sphere) and Pro Builder Shape (Cone) behave the same way?

Note: Both objects have the same scale.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do they have the same scale?

Comment: Yes, x:1, y:1, z:1